# Eclipse gcov missing highlighting in code

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcov

I build my C++ project with "Generate gcov information", I run it under the "Gcov" profiler from the Linux Tools repository, and I get a nice coverage overview in the "gcov" view. But when I double click a file (one with about 92 % for example) the editor view that pops up has **no** coverage highlighting.

I observe this on both x86_64/xenial/Mars and i386/hardy/Luna.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am seeing same behavior on xenial/Neon

Comment: This is for me the same using eclipse neon and oxygen on a Ubuntu 17.10 host.

Comment: I have the same issue with eclipse oxygen.

Comment: I manually deleted all .gcda files inside my project and it works again.  Not sure you were running into the same issue.  Just FYI.